# Can bounties be taken away or re-awarded?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Let's take this case. I have an open bounty for 100 rep. Someone posts a long and extensive answer, the OP accepts it and the complete bounty is awarded. However after a day someone else posts a better answer, that solves the problem in a better way and this brings the realization that the first answer wasn't worth the bounty. I know that answers can be unaccepted but can bounties be moved? Or are they final?

To clarify, this did not yet happen, I was just wondering about it after seeing a question where the bounty awarded answer had 1 vote and another not accepted had 12.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No; once a bounty is awarded, it's permanently awarded.  Only in certain cases such as fraud are bounties ever overturned, and that's done by Stack Overflow employees on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: So if there comes a better answer at a later point, it's pretty much the bounty awarders fault for not waiting longer?

Comment: @JulianE.:  Pretty much, yes.  But to be fair, bounties, much like votes and accepting answers, are subject to the same impulse behavior by those looking for an answer; they see something good so they run with it.

Comment: @JulianE.: The idea is that you reward good answers, not "best" answers.